# Cycle detection with Mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation, recursion

Suppose we have [cellular automaton on a network](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/227998/how-to-simulate-a-cellular-automaton-on-a-network). For simplicity, we will use matrix notation.

```
ClearAll[adjMatrix, initStates, nodeStep, allStep];
(*Adjacency matrix*)
adjMatrix = {{0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}};
(*Initial states of nodes*)
initStates ={0, 1, 1, 0};  

nodeStep[adjMatrix_, states_, node_] :=
  With[{inputs = Pick[states, adjMatrix[[All, node]], 1]},
    (*Any suitable function here*)
    BitXor @@ inputs
   ];

allStep[adjMatrix_, states_] := 
  nodeStep[adjMatrix, states, #] & /@ Range[Length@states];
```

Starting from some initial state, the function  `allStep` is applied iteratively.
It is known that sooner or later we will get *a cycle*.

For test example:
{0, 1, 1, 0} → {1, 1, 1, 1} → {1, 0, 1, 1} → {1, 1, 1, 1} → ...
(period 2)

But first, not necessarily straight from the initial state. Second, about the cycle length (period), it is *only known* that it is smaller than $2^{size}$

I have not been able to find a way to *simultaneously* detect the cycle and determine its length. For *detection* I use

```
data = NestWhileList[allStep[adjMatrix, #]&, initStates, Unequal, All];
```

and then we can find the length of the cycle.
Several ways have been suggested here.

- `FindRepeat`. It fails with period 1
- `SequencePosition`. I do not understand what should be M in my case:
  `SequencePosition[data, Take[data, M]]`?
- `FindTransientRepeat`. It works, but much slower than brutal force method
- `First@Differences@Flatten@Position[data, Last@data]`

Some timings:

```
data = ContinuedFraction[(Sqrt[12] + 2)/7, 100004];
Timing[Length@Last@FindTransientRepeat[data, 2]]
{0.499203, 6}
Timing[r = SequencePosition[data, Take[data, -10]]; 
 r[[-1, 1]] - r[[-2, 1]]]
{0.0156001, 6}
Timing[First@Differences@Flatten@Position[data, Last@data]]
{0.0468003, 6}
```

Comment: Save the states in a list and use `FindTransientRepeat`. See here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175338/find-cycle-length-in-a-list?rq=1

Comment: Alternatively, if you need to avoid storing lots of data, you can run one process 1 step at a time and a copy of this process 2 steps at a time. At each stage check if their states are equal - then you know there's a cycle.  This is like the old Tortoise and Hare trick with linked lists: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Floyd's_Tortoise_and_Hare

Comment: I wrote up implementations of Floyd's and Brent's algorithms, but you don't seem to have provided a concrete example I could try them out on.

Comment: @Bill timings are added. But what "-10" means?

Comment: @J. M., all post completely rewritten

Comment: Your example doesn't exhibit cycling behavior. Could you perhaps give an example that does so?

Comment: @J. M.
First, the repetition of the same state is a cycle with a period 1, and it must be detected.
`NestWhileList` do this.
 Secondly, I changed the test case, now it is period 2.
Third, to see the difference of Timing, one should test matrices with size ~10^2 - 10^3

Comment: @Bill  
Sorry, but in my case, we do not know in advance either the length of the cycle, or where it starts. So `SequencePosition` not work (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is [Brent's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Brent%27s_algorithm).

```
brentCycleDetection[adjMatrix_, states_] :=
  Module[{power = 1, lam = 1, tortoise = states, 
    hare = allStep[adjMatrix, states]},
   While[tortoise != hare,
     If[ power == lam,
                 tortoise = hare;
                 power *= 2;
                 lam = 0];
    hare = allStep[adjMatrix, hare];
    lam += 1;
    ];
   lam
   ];
```

Here is typical example:

```
size = 13; adjMatrix = RandomInteger[1, {size, size}]; states = 
 RandomInteger[1, size];

Timing[brentCycleDetection[adjMatrix, states]]
{0.140401, 510}

Timing[myCycleDetection[adjMatrix, states]]
{1.54441, 510}
```